# Typings for a function allowing both a promise and a callback

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using [universalify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/universalify) to generate a function that by default returns a promise but also supports a callback as the last parameter (which would then not return a promise). How would I write proper Typescript typings to describe this in my `index.d.ts` file?

At the moment, I'm having to duplicate my function typings in the form of function overloads to support the promise:

```
declare function someFunc(opts): Promise<any>
declare function someFunc(opts: object, callback: (error: Error | null, result: any | void) => any): void
```

When I'm using this terminology in larger projects, it adds a large development burden when I'm having to rename by typings twice or three times over.

What's the conventional way to achieve this?

Comment: Doesn't your IDE help you with renaming things?

Comment: @Bergi It does but that would just be running away from the problem.

Comment: I don't think there's a problem. If you want to provide an overload with a callback, it's only natural to have to repeat the function name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're talking about [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) and I think they *are* the conventional way to do this.

Since TS3.0 or so you could use [rest tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions), [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), and [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) to avoid overloads, something like this:

```
type Callback<T> = (error: Error | null, result: T | void) => any;
declare function someFunc2<C extends [Callback<any>] | []>(
    opts: object,
    ...[callback]: C
): C extends [Callback<any>] ? void : Promise<any>;

const promiseResult2 = someFunc2({});
const voidResult2 = someFunc2({}, (e, r) => r);
```

But the cure might be worse than the disease here.  I'd stick with overloads, I think, unless your use case really requires single call signatures.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwGccBbEAMTTAAocAHDAgLnhwCMArcDASmYAUYJLARAAeKKgCeAPgDcAKFCRYCFOmx5CJcpRr0mLDlwA08MFAgRWUMAGtmVEDEExmAUWc4Y8AD7xUyJamcASBGMwSkr7wAG44WMDc8AC80vCRvLHxwAryYHgEGPC0gsTCIABKIKEQRclapBToVADeAL7cCvmohVkJVTV1DTrN7aaOwUmp8DCd8vIYkrQIAMIWVja2ogAqafWOnq7wHi7RAUEz1WHM29FxCVNpkQpK0HBIlBr4RI2UAEyiFbwEAADwwIFQwAI8AA2mtLNY7OIpNIALrRGGo6RUeTwPEsfTMNicTDGXH4gB0VJh5gRm1RzBW8kyQNB4Mh0Lh60RW0iaPgAH4+sB4PxSuVkTJct1eiUhCIBmE-ilhk0wH9Wh0ugUivdgIrasr6j8RurNeMQJMUmlZgogA)